# Automatically assigning model field values in Django

Tags: django, django-models

Is there a way to automatically set field values for models in Django when defining the model?  This could be used for storing something like a timestamp (for example), but also for creating a field which is constructed as some function of the others.

In other words, I'm looking for something like this:

class Foo(models.Model):

```
spam = models.CharField(max_length=2000)
my_other_field = ###?

def generate_my_other_field():
    #Some algorithm to determine the value of my_other_field
```

Comment: Do you want to store these generated values in the database? Or just have them available when you're looking at the model instances?

Comment: I'd like to generate them when the other fields are defined as well - basically, the way an initializer would work in Python. There might be a cleaner way to do this, but it's the easiest that I can think of.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, there is a way. From [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#default):

> **Field.default**
>
> The default value for
> the field. This can be a value or a
> callable object. If callable it will
> be called every time a new object is
> created.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't realize that default values could be callable functions.

Comment: The trick is to make sure you assign the function as the default, not the result - so (eg) `default=datetime.datetime.now` rather than `default=datetime.datetime.now()`.